# Quick launch menu missing

Tags: sharepoint-2010, quicklaunch

I have created a team site in a site collection.
I have modified the default page of the team site to use the "Blank Web Part Page" layout.
I am an administrator of the site collection and I can see the quick launch menu on the default page of the team site.

I have granted a user "Full Control" permission on the team site.
The user can not see the quick launch menu on the default page of the team site.
I want to know why and how I can fix this issue.
I have googled for a while but without success. 
I hope a StackOverflow user will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by looking at another team site in the web application.
I have created a new page with the "Blank Web Part Page" layout.
Then I have set the new page as the welcome page of the team site.
Now the user can see the quick launch menu.